# Map app for iPad that works while you're not connected to WiFi or 3G?

Tags: applications, ipad, mapping

About to drive across country and, while we're sporting iPhones, it sure would be nice if the navigator could use our iPad, non-3G, version to view maps while we're traveling. I've looked through the app store but the field is littered with impostors and the carnage of the poorly implemented.

Does such a thing exist? Is there a well-made, offline map app for the iPad?

Notes:

- I'd need it to cover Canada (Eastern and Atlantic) and the North East United States (Maine, New Hampshire, Vermont, upper state New York).
- Obviously I don't expect it to do any positioning (does the iPad 2 even have a GPS radio?) so an app that just called up street level maps would be fine. We're old enough to understand how to find our place in the world without a GPS lock on. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These apps might be of interest:

- [Galileo Offline Maps](http://galileo-app.com/)
- [OffMaps 2](http://www.offmaps.com/)
- [Comparison of iOS Map apps](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Apple_iOS)

According to OffMaps2 [library search](http://www.offmaps.com/offline-maps-library.htm), maps of New York, Maine, New Hampshire, Vermont and parts of Canada are available.

Hope that helps, and enjoy your trip!

Comment: This looks generally excellent (though the price is a bit deceptive...looks like it's $8 if you want it with unlimited maps). But it's missing the non-city areas (where I'm more likely to get lost) in the East.

Comment: I noticed that in the maps as well; If find anything better I'll let you know.

Comment: I've included another app to my original answer that might help you.

Comment: Personally, and despite the warning from the developer, I'd buy the old version of OffMaps. The new version makes you pay for downloading maps, while the old one allows to to download maps for free.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Galileo](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/galileo-offline-maps/id321745474?mt=8). I tested it earlier and it works very good!

Comment: Tried it out. The Mobile Map creator tool is...not good. Cool idea, but I had lots of trouble creating a map that covered my whole trip area. It has promise. Just needs some refinement.